# How to focus when an error occurs in react-hook-form Controller?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I am rendering a custom component using the `Controller` of react-hook-form.

If an error occurs when using `register`, focus is normal, but the Controller does not.

I was able to find a way to handle an error when the Custom Component processes only a single input, but I couldn't find a way to handle it when it has multiple inputs.

Form.js

```
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import CustomInput from "./CustomInput";
import * as yup from "yup";

const schema = yup.object({
  name: yup.object().shape({
    first: yup.string().required(),
    last: yup.string().required(),
  }),
});
function Form() {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { name: { first: "", last: "" } },
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        name="name"
        control={control}
        rules={{ required: true }}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <CustomInput
            value={field.value}
            onChange={(value) => field.onChange(value)}
            errors={errors}
          />
        )}
      />
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

CustomInput.js

```
function CustomInput({ value, onChange, errors }) {
  const changeFirst = (e) => {
    onChange({ first: e.target.value, last: value?.last });
  };

  const changeLast = (e) => {
    onChange({ first: value?.first, last: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={value.first} onChange={changeFirst} />
      <input type="text" value={value.last} onChange={changeLast} />
      {errors?.name && (
        <p className="errmsg">
          {errors?.name?.first?.message || errors?.name?.last?.message}
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default CustomInput;
```

​How can I get error focus when there are multiple inputs in a custom component?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`setFocus`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setFocus) from RHF. First, detect when the `errors` object changes and then find the first field which has the object and call `setFocus(field)`:

```
const {
  setFocus,
  formState: { errors },
  ...
} = useForm<FormValues>();

React.useEffect(() => {
  const firstError = Object.keys(errors).reduce((field, a) => {
    return !!errors[field] ? field : a;
  }, null);

  if (firstError) {
    setFocus(firstError);
  }
}, [errors, setFocus]);
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: As I wrote, if the error type is Object or Array, how can I handle it?
Is there only one way to process them one by one as you wrote?

Comment: @extradeck did you open my codesandbox and try it out?

Comment: Yes. But I wonder if the type of error can't be handled as 'errors.name.firstname.message' instead of 'errors.firstname.message'.

Comment: @extradeck you're using RHF the wrong way, you should never have to control the form state yourself, if you're using nested component you should use `useFormContext`. I fixed your code in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/69719627-how-to-focus-when-an-error-occurs-in-react-hook-form-controller-forked-lfuqy?file=/src/App.tsx) codesandbox

Comment: isn't `useEffect` only triggered on first validation? as errors is still the same object, it won't trigger when its props are updated

Answer (score 8):

What controls focus is the "ref" and for some reason when you use Controller the "ref" does not get associated properly to the underlying element, so you'll have to use ref from "register" instead of from "field".

```
import { FC } from 'react'
import { Controller, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form'
import { TextField, TextFieldProps } from '@mui/material'

export const RhfTextField: FC<{ name: string } & TextFieldProps> = ({
  name,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const { control, register } = useFormContext()

  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      defaultValue=""
      render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <TextField
          {...rest}
          {...field}
          ref={register(name).ref} // overriding field.ref
          // you can do {...register(name)} and omit {...field}
          // but showing this explicitly for demonstration purposes
          error={!!error}
          helperText={error?.message ?? ''}
        />
      )}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on @NearHuscarl answer, I create the typescript version:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const firstError = (
      Object.keys(errors) as Array<keyof typeof errors>
    ).reduce<keyof typeof errors | null>((field, a) => {
      const fieldKey = field as keyof typeof errors;
      return !!errors[fieldKey] ? fieldKey : a;
    }, null);

    if (firstError) {
      setFocus(firstError);
    }
  }, [errors, setFocus]);
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you use `mode: "onTouched"` to validate because the errors don't change on submit. Adding `isSubmitting` to the dependency array seems to resolve it though

Comment: Getting: Type '"root"' is not assignable to type '"firstName" | "lastName" | "email" | ...

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by [arcanereinz solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74529792/657669), you can use the `inputRef` without defining `ref`.

I think there is a bug in MUI, it's really odd this behaviour

Working codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-panna-ttste0?file=/src/App.tsx

```js
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm();
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
      <Controller
        name="foo"
        control={control}
        rules={{ required: true }}
        render={({ field: { ref, ...field }, fieldState }) => (
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            variant="outlined"
            error={Boolean(fieldState.error)}
            inputRef={ref}
            {...field}
          />
        )}
      />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a working example of how to set focus in case of errors with `Controller`

```
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import type { ReactNode } from 'react';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Controller, useForm, useFormState } from 'react-hook-form';
import { setTimeout } from 'timers';
import * as yup from 'yup';


const TextInput = (props: any) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value || '');
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null); // Create a reference
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(props.value);
  }, [props.value]); // watch props.value in case of change update it

  const { errors } = useFormState({
    control: props.control,
    name: props.name,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Focus the input element if there's an error
    if (errors?.[props.name]) {
      inputRef.current?.focus();
    }
  }, [errors, props.name]);

   
  return (
    <>
      <input
        ref={inputRef} // Attach the reference to the input element
        name={props.name}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setValue(e.target.value);
          if (props.onChange) props.onChange(e); // we are sending down e.target.value here
        }}
        value={value}
        onBlur={props.onBlur}
      />
      <p>{errors?.[props.name]?.message as ReactNode}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const Test = () => {
  
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    setValue,
    // formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(
      yup.object().shape({
        firstName: yup.string().required('required'),
        lastName: yup.string().required('last name is required'),
      })
    ),
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: 'hello',
      lastName: 'world',
    },
  });
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => alert(JSON.stringify(data));

  // update component from outside
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setValue('lastName', 'ddd');
    }, 1000);
  }, [setValue]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input
        {...register('firstName')}
        placeholder="first"
      />
      

      <Controller
        control={control}
        rules={{
          maxLength: 100,
          required: true,
        }}
        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
          <TextInput
            placeholder="Last name"
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
            name={'lastName'}
            control={control}
          />
        )}
        name="lastName"
      />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. Using ref was in the right direction. I feel I have to share that I found this didn't work:

```
              <Controller
                control={form.control}
                name="startDate"
                render={({
                  field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
                  fieldState: { error, invalid }
                }) => (
                  <TextField
                    inputRef={startDateRef}
```

But, rather I had to put the ref on the `inputProps`.

```
              <Controller
                control={form.control}
                name="startDate"
                render={({
                  field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
                  fieldState: { error, invalid }
                }) => (
                  <TextField
                    inputProps={ ref: startDateRef, ...}
```

And, then I could do this - I know my start/end date inputs are the only ones possibly erroring, so it was simpler to just:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (form.formState.errors) {
      if (form.formState.errors.startDate) {
        startDateRef.current?.focus();
      } else {
        endDateRef.current?.focus();
      }
    }
  }, [form.formState.errors, form.setFocus]);
```

NOTE: The particular setup for the Controller here, and the way I'm destructuring in the render is not the inconsequential to what I'm trying to share here. The point is using the `inputProps->ref` instead of `inputRef` was what finally got focus moved to the input with error.

Answer (score -1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0) {
        const firstError = Object.keys(errors)[0] as keyof typeof errors;
        setFocus(firstError);
    }
}, [errors, setFocus]);
```

Comment: Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question.

Comment: Solution is much cleaner as the accepted answer IMO

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setFocus` from `useForm` hook as described below:

```
const {
  setFocus,
  formState: { errors },
  ...
} = useForm<FormValues>();

React.useEffect(() => {
  const firstError = Object.keys(errors).reduce((field, a) => {
    return !!errors[field] ? field : a;
  }, null);

  if (firstError) {
    setFocus(firstError);
  }
}, [errors, setFocus]);
```

In order to get the `setFocus()` work with `Controller` correctly you need to add the `ref` prop to controlled input like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
      <Controller
        name="foo"
        control={control}
        rules={{ required: true }}
        render={({ field: { ref } }) => (
          <TextField
            ...
            inputRef={ref}
          />
        )}
      />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Or to achieve the same thing with `Select` component from `react-select`:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="states"
  render={({ field: { onChange, value, ref } }) => (
    <Select
      value={value}
      onChange={val => onChange(val)}
      options={states}
      placeholder="Choose states"
      ref={ref}
    />
  )}
/>;
```